# global class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, global, declaration

I have Errorlog.vb in my vb.net 2008 project. It is for public class.

> Public Class ErrorLogger

I want to call this public class anywhere. So on EACH vb file I use

> import "mainproject name".ErrorLogger

How can I declare once some where at the beginning and that class will be availabe through out the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project properties, open the References tab, and select the namespace from the list of "Imported namespaces" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I don't see "ErrorLogger" in the list even it is decleared as Public class. Any idea?

Comment: ErrorLogger is the class name, not the namespace.  You need to select the namespace that contains the ErrorLogger class.  This would typically be the same as your project name.

Answer (score 1):

In the Solution Explorer, right click on your project and chose the Properties option. Then click on the References tabs. In this tab, you can add new Import that are Project width.

Comment: Hi Stephan, I found Unused Ref, Ref Paths on top and Add at the bottom. Which I have to choose?

Comment: You are also right. I am a new learner so I couldn't understand what you are saying first. Thanks anyway.